# Problem with sudo apt-get update -qq on boost 1.53 package

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, boost

I am getting an error when I am trying to add `boost 1.53 PPA`.
Let me show what I'm doing;

1. adding repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apokluda/boost1.53 -y
   ```
2. updating the apt

   ```
   sudo apt-get update -qq
   ```

But after few minutes I get this error:

```
    W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/apokluda/boost1.53/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.

E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/apokluda/boost1.53/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried to do just `apt-get update` without `-qq` but it does not work. 
The PPA's website says to do just this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apokluda/boost1.53
sudo apt-get update
```

but I am not succeeding in adding this repository. What should I do?

Comment: This PPA does not support anything newer than 12.10.

Comment: i've another option to replace and make work my code?

Comment: Do you need 1.53 specifically?

Comment: i think it so. cause its an tibia server. and boost is an dependency.

Comment: I have no idea what tibia is. At any rate, Ubuntu 14.04 and above have boost 1.54 and above. If not, you'll probably have to build from source (assuming the libraries you need require building).